# ipcs remove shared memeory segment by deleting key

Tags: linux, command, shared-memory

My boss wants me to remove the service that is using this memory segement. He said you remove it by key. 
I have no idea what he is talking about.

```
[casper@casper01s]:~> ipcs -m

------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status
0x26b023e3 689864705  casper    666        2500       0
```

Comment: The manual pages for `ipcs` and `ipcrm` would be a good place to start...

Comment: ipcrm -m gets rid of it - thanks